# custom spring login form looping and never authenticating

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I had this working with JSP but I want to use Thymeleaf. Here is the issue, once I login the the page is redirected back to the login page. I cannot get passed the login page even though in the form action I send it to /userLogin and catch it in the controller. I will post a snippet of google chromes inspection so you can see what I am talking about. It doesn't even display the form action URL.

spring-security.xml

```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.practice.controller"></context:component-scan>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="Drew">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="drew" authorities="admin" password="letmein" />
                <security:user name="mike" authorities="admin" password="eagles" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/form" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
        <security:form-login
                login-page="/login" />
    </security:http>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
</head>

<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>

<form name="f" th:action="@{/userLogin}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please Login</legend>

        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="u_username"/>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="p_password"/>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String showLogin(){
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getUserLogin(){
        return "form";
    }

}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.practice.controller"></context:component-scan>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

inspection view in browser

[image: 1]

----------------UPDATE 1-----------------

Not sure if this has anything to do with it but if you notice in my dispatcher-servlet.xml I have the following:

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

On the thymeleaf site it mentioned using this method: [thymeleaf with spring-MVC](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html)

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  </bean>
```

Now I am using .jsp but with thymeleaf technology. I tired to following the instructions but it did not work.

Advice? I am starting to narrow down the issue to perhaps a thymeleaf issue but I am really not sure.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're talking about.  Is there a specific issue that you're having trouble with?  Do you get some kind of error message telling you of the error?

Comment: @Makoto No error message. I put in the username and password, hit submit and it renders the login form again. It other words I cannot get pass the login form. The form submits to /userLogin and in the controller I catch it and return form.jsp. However this is not working.

Comment: @Makoto please see update 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form for login should be submitted to the URL j_spring_security_check.
Delete /userLogin controller and set form:

```
<th:form name="f" th:action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
```

or

```
<form name="f" action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
```

Comment: It did not work but I am reading http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html and I beginning to think I should not use .jsp

Comment: Try <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config='true'>

Comment: No that did not work either. Just to confirm here I can use Thymeleaf inside a JSP correct? I am trying to use Thymeleaf inside a JSP and not use any JSTL or JSP tags. I am doing this it is just easier to handle with spring framework.

Comment: You can. The frontend layer should not be significant. The problem is spring configuration. You can publish it in githup?

Comment: Thank you for the help https://github.com/drewjocham/springIssue.git, login.jsp is the file you are looking for under the WEB-INF/jsps/ directory

Comment: Solved. Sorry but my code have a error. Mix th:form tag with form tag. The original error is that the form for login should be submitted to the URL j_spring_security_check

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: Yes if I drop the th: out it works, Thymeleaf in general is not working in my project. I just tried to bring in the css file via thymeleaf and it didn't work.